# How to select min and max values of a column in a datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, select, datatable

For the following datatable column, what is the fastest way to get the min and max values?

```
AccountLevel  
0  
1  
2  
3
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
int minAccountLevel = int.MaxValue;
int maxAccountLevel = int.MinValue;
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
    int accountLevel = dr.Field<int>("AccountLevel");
    minAccountLevel = Math.Min(minAccountLevel, accountLevel);
    maxAccountLevel = Math.Max(maxAccountLevel, accountLevel);
}
```

Yes, this really is the fastest way.  Using the Linq `Min` and `Max` extensions will always be slower because you have to iterate twice.  You could potentially use Linq `Aggregate`, but the syntax isn't going to be much prettier than this already is.

Comment: Yes, this is what SLaks suggests, to use for loop as the fastest way.

Comment: Yes, but I think it should be  
{
    int accountLevel = dr.Field<int>("AccountLevel");
    min = Math.Min(min, accountLevel);
    max = Math.Max(max, accountLevel);
}

isn't it?

Comment: @Ahmed: Sorry, typo in the variable assignments.  Fixed.

Comment: I may be a little late to the party, but won't minAccountLevel ALWAYS be equal to int.MinValue because accountLevel can never be less than int.MinValue?  And the same goes for maxAccountLevel and int.MaxValue, no?

Comment: @Welton yeah, I messed up and transposed the first two lines. The "min" should be initialized to `Int32.MaxValue` and the "max" should be initialized to `Int32.MinValue`, such that the first row (if there are any rows at all) will always update those.

Comment: @Aaronaught good to know this is as fast as linq as it was my approach too, though chaowman's answer looks interesting...

Answer (score 123):

Easiar approach on datatable could be:

```
int minLavel = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("min([AccountLevel])", string.Empty));
```

Comment: This is the best approach but u are missing one thing the use of `[]` in the above code.. e.g

`int minLavel = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("min([AccountLevel])", string.Empty));`

Without the Square Brackets it gave me an error.

Comment: I am not very experienced with this, but my program got much faster after I started using "compute" instead of loops etc. You just need to make sure your data is in the correct format to be able to use compute.

Answer (score 16):

Use LINQ. It works just fine on datatables, as long as you convert the rows collection to an IEnumerable.

```
List<int> levels = AccountTable.AsEnumerable().Select(al => al.Field<int>("AccountLevel")).Distinct().ToList();
int min = levels.Min();
int max = levels.Max();
```

Edited to fix syntax; it's tricky when using LINQ on DataTables, and aggregating functions are fun, too.

Yes, it can be done with one query, but you will need to generate a list of results, then use .Min() and .Max() as aggregating functions in separate statements.

Comment: But it requires two iterations.

Comment: Somehow I don't think that `Distinct` will speed this up - it has to hash every element, whereas `Min` and `Max` just do a compare.

Answer (score 12):

This worked fine for me

```
int  max = Convert.ToInt32(datatable_name.AsEnumerable()
                        .Max(row => row["column_Name"]));
```

Comment: This is cooooool! Awesome

Answer (score 6):

The most efficient way to do this (believe it or not) is to make two variables and write a `for` loop.

Answer (score 5):

```
var answer = accountTable.Aggregate(new { Min = int.MinValue, Max = int.MaxValue }, 
                                        (a, b) => new { Min = Math.Min(a.Min, b.Field<int>("AccountLevel")),
                                                        Max = Math.Max(a.Max, b.Field<int>("AccountLevel")) });
int min = answer.Min;
int max = answer.Max;
```

1 iteration, linq style :)

Comment: haven't tried this yet, but it looks promising - have you compared it to the straight-up for loop for performance?

Comment: what type is `accountTable`? DataTable objects don't seem to support `Aggregate` for me...

Answer (score 4):

another way of doing this is

```
int minLavel = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Select("AccountLevel=min(AccountLevel)")[0][0]);
```

I am not sure on the performace part but this does give the correct output

Comment: I tested this on a DataTable containing 125k rows. It is terribly slow.

Answer (score 2):

```
var min = dt.AsEnumerable().Min(row => row["AccountLevel"]);
var max = dt.AsEnumerable().Max(row => row["AccountLevel"]);
```

Comment: Please add a comment on your answer, code only could not be clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
Session["MinDate"] = dtRecord.Compute("Min(AccountLevel)", string.Empty);
Session["MaxDate"] = dtRecord.Compute("Max(AccountLevel)", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate on **why** this is is the fastest way? Any arguments can be helpful for others to take or skip your advice in favour of the other posts.

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise, this should be comparable. Use Select statement and Sort to get a list and then pick the first or last (depending on your sort order).

```
var col = dt.Select("AccountLevel", "AccountLevel ASC");

var min = col.First();
var max = col.Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how my solution compares performance wise to previous answers.

I understand that the initial question was: What is the fastest way to get min and max values in a DataTable object, this may be one way of doing it:

```
DataView view = table.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "AccountLevel";
DataTable sortedTable = view.ToTable();
int min = sortedTable.Rows[0].Field<int>("AccountLevel");
int max = sortedTable.Rows[sortedTable.Rows.Count-1].Field<int>("AccountLevel");
```

It's an easy way of achieving the same result without looping. But performance will need to be compared with previous answers. Thought I love Cylon Cats answer most.