# find max value from Dataset

Tags: c#

How we find Maximum and minimum value from DataSet

Comment: !!! Maximum and minimum value of what??? Please be clear .

Comment: Kind a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442525/how-to-select-min-and-max-values-of-a-column-in-a-datatable

Comment: if you are employed in IT or even just a student then you will know that details are very important for an accurate answer, yet you provide none... try and edit your question and include some more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use linq to object like this

```
dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Max(row => row[ColumnName]);

dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Min(row => row[ColumnName]);
```