# Get Maximum value code from a datatable in c# throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#

I have a datatable similar to

```
Rank  Year  Value
1     1990  1234556.5676
2     2000  12313.1212 
3     2010  131242.1234
```

I have the following code which I wrote with the help of the following thread: [How to select min and max values of a column in a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442525/how-to-select-min-and-max-values-of-a-column-in-a-datatable)

```
double dMaxValue = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dsView.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    double dValue = dr.Field<double>("Value");
    dMaxValue = Math.Max(dMaxValue, dValue);
}
```

This is throwing an error "Specified cast is not valid". What am I missing here and also how can I get the value of the year column once I find the MAX Value? The year needs to be returned to the calling program.

**EDIT- (SOLUTION):**  With the help of SLacks I figured out how to accomplish the task. Firstly, I found that the data in my datatable was of type string so converted the value to double and determine the maximum value. Then used a variable to find the corresponding year.

```
string sYear = string.Empty;
double dMaxValue = double.MinValue;
foreach (DataRow dr in dsView.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    double dValue = Convert.ToDouble(dr.Field<string>("Value"));
    if (dValue > dMaxValue)
    {
        sYear = dr["Year"].ToString();
    }
    dMaxValue = Math.Max(dMaxValue, dValue);                            
}
return sYear;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Value` column is probably a `decimal`, or perhaps a `float`.

[You cannot cast directly from a boxed `float` to a `double`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx), so you need an extra cast.

It would be better to use the actual type of your field from the dataset, or to change that type to `Double`.

Comment: I tried all datatypes by changing the code to `float dValue = dr.Field<float>("Value");` and `decimal dValue = dr.Field<decimal>("Value");` but no luck. Is this the right way to check? Since I don't have access to the dataset.. so I really can't edit it. How can I find the type of the column from a dataset?

Comment: @user: `dr["Value"].GetType()`, or `table.Columns["Value"].DataType`

Comment: Thanks for your initial suggestion. I thought for a minute and found that the dataset has all column data as strings. I have resolved it using the following: `double dValue = Convert.ToDouble(dr.Field<string>("Value"));`. But now how can I find the corresponding Year? Is there a simple solution for it?

Comment: You need to make a separate variable for the year and assign `if` the value is larger.

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the year?

You can sort the dataview:

```
           http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx
```

and then pluck the year from the sorted view.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (using System.Linq and Extensions, note the let variable for the conversion):

```
double maxVal = 0; // supposing all your values are > 0
var maxRow = (from row in dsView.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() 
   let Val = Convert.ToDouble(row.Field<string>("Value"))
   where Val > maxVal
   select new {maxVal = Val, Year = row.Field<int>("Year")}).Last();

return maxRow.Year;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `Max` can't do that.

Comment: @cudahead, the data in dataset is string type. So I tweaked your code to `var maxRow = (from row in dsView.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
select new
{
  Val = Convert.ToDouble(row.Field<string>("Value")),
  Year = Convert.ToDouble(row.Field<string>("Year"))
}).Max(x => x.Val);`. Firstly, this code doesn't work and I don't get Year in maxRow. Did I miss something?

Comment: I thought of a solution with a let variable. Please find my updated post above!

Comment: cudahead, I still don't see Year or Val in maxRow. I am sure I am missing something..

Comment: Ok, now it should work (once again updated). Note that there is no Max() used here. Please check!