# Found minimum and maximum value from dataset containing multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, datatable, dataset

I am developing an asp.net application where i have a dataset having 3 tables i.e. `ds.Tables[0], Tables[1] and Tables[2]`

I need to find minimum number and maximum number out of all the 3 tables of dataset. How to do that?

I found similar question in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442525/how-to-select-min-and-max-values-of-a-column-in-a-datatable) but not sure how that would help me getting my way?

**UPDATED:**

```
 double minValue = double.MinValue;
 double maxValue = double.MaxValue;
 foreach (DataRow dr in dtSMPS.Rows)
 {
            double actualValue = dr.Field<double>("TOTAL_SUM");  // This fails specifying type cast error
            minValue = Math.Min(minValue, actualValue);
            maxValue = Math.Max(maxValue, actualValue);
 }
```

Please guide! Thanks.

Comment: do u mean min or max from an integer/decimal field that is a column in each of the 3 tables?

Comment: Its an decimal(float) field in all the 3 tables..

Comment: and have they the same column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an extra for loop added to the solution you have already linked to.
I.e.

```
int minAccountLevel = int.MaxValue;
int maxAccountLevel = int.MinValue;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
var table = ds.Tables[i];
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
    int accountLevel = dr.Field<int>("AccountLevel");
    minAccountLevel = Math.Min(minAccountLevel, accountLevel);
    maxAccountLevel = Math.Max(maxAccountLevel, accountLevel);
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input.As mentioned in one of my comments that datatype of my column is decimal. Hence i am changing the datatype to decimal but the code fails.

Comment: Is it nullable? Try checking if dr["column"] == DBNull.Value and you can try using Convert.ToDecimal(dr["column"]) if it is not null.

Answer (score 1):

If they have the same column name suppose 'decimalValue' then:

```
decimal minAccountLevel = decimal.zero;
decimal maxAccountLevel = decimal.zero;
for (int i = 0; i < dts.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dts.Tables[i].Rows)
            {
                decimal accountLevel = decimal.Parse(dr["decimalValue"].ToString());
                minAccountLevel = Math.Min(minAccountLevel, accountLevel);
                maxAccountLevel = Math.Max(maxAccountLevel, accountLevel);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can select the min and max for each DataTable using the [`Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) method on each DataTable.

**Disclaimer** this is not safe code; you should check for errors, nulls, and make it more readable.

Something like this should work:

```
decimal max = Math.Max(Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables[2].Compute("MAX(AccountLevel)","").ToString()),  Math.Max(Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables[0].Compute("Max(AccountLevel)","").ToString()),Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables[1].Compute("Max(AccountLevel)","").ToString()));
```