# Calculate min and max C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to work out Max value from the datagridview.
Here is my whole code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class HRData
    {
        public int? HeartRate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int? Speed
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int? Power
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int? Altitude
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Heart rate={0}, Speed={1}, Power={2}, Altitude={3}", HeartRate, Speed, Power, Altitude);
        }
    }





    public static class HRDataReader
    {
        static private int? ConvertValue(string[] values, int index)
        {
            if (index >= values.Length)
                return null;
            int value;
            if (int.TryParse(values[index], out value))
                return value;
            return null;
        }

        static public IList<HRData> Read(string fileName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                string line;

                // First: Skip to the correct section.
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    if (line == "[HRData]")
                        break;

                // Now: Read the HRData
                List<HRData> data = new List<HRData>();
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("[") && line.EndsWith("]"))
                        break;
                    line = line.Trim().Replace("\t", " "); // Remove all tabs.
                    while (line.Contains("  ")) // Remove all duplicate spaces.
                        line = line.Replace("  ", " ");
                    string[] values = line.Split(' '); // Split the line up.
                    data.Add(new HRData
                    {
                        HeartRate = ConvertValue(values, 0),
                        Speed = ConvertValue(values, 1),
                        Power = ConvertValue(values, 2),
                        Altitude = ConvertValue(values, 3)
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }
        }
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

            IList<HRData> data = HRDataReader.Read(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "HeartRate", HeaderText = "Heart rate", DataPropertyName = "HeartRate" });
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Speed", HeaderText = "Speed", DataPropertyName = "Speed" });
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Power", HeaderText = "Power", DataPropertyName = "Power" });
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Altitude", HeaderText = "Altitude", DataPropertyName = "Altitude" });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

            int maxSpeed = Speed.Max();
            maxSpeed = maxSpeed / 10;
            string MaxSpeed = Convert.ToString(maxSpeed);
            textBox1.Text = MaxSpeed;    
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm getting an error on 'int maxSpeed = Speed.Max();'

The error message says that "The name 'Speed' does not exist in a current context"

I don't know what value should I put in there to represent one of my columns. Hope someone will be able to help me with this issue. Thank You.

Comment: This is a lot of code. Can you trim it down a bit? It might help you identifying the problem yourself, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speed is not a class or an object, so it doesn't know what it is. You have to use a function and a collection:

```
int maxSpeed = data.Max(x => x.Speed.Value);
```

[See the documentation on list max for more information and sample code.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535031%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: updated my answer to work with list.

Comment: comes up with error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
"

Comment: Does that work? I converted the int? to an int value

Comment: @user2375636 Please vote up or mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `Math.Max Method (Double, Double)` and `Math.Min Method (Double, Double)` included in standard .NET C# Library

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
int minAccountLevel = int.MaxValue;
int maxAccountLevel = int.MinValue;
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in table.Rows)
{
    int accountLevel = dr.Cells["Speed"];
    minAccountLevel = Math.Min(minAccountLevel, accountLevel);
    maxAccountLevel = Math.Max(maxAccountLevel, accountLevel);
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2442717/1908499

Comment: It crashes on line "foreach (DataRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)" with message Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Edited!