# Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'string'

Tags: c#

## I want to display the largest value in the ["id"] field in massbox

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
       {           
        string s=null;
        foreach (DataRow a in amDataSet.students.Rows)
        {
            if (a["id"] > s)
            {
                s = a["id"].ToString();
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(s);
        }
```

Comment: What you want to achieve is quite impossible to understand. What do you mean by "the largest value" if you are trying to compare a string with a unknown object? What do you expect `a["id"]` to be?

Comment: i have a field named "id" data type it  int I want to show the largest number in the message box @ Federico Dipuma

Comment: "a" is a datarow pointer in the dataset @Federico Dipuma

Comment: @AhmedKareem You know it's an int but the compiler doesn't. You need to cast it, e.g. (int)(a["id"]). Also `int > string` makes no sense, so it's unclear what you're really trying to achieve here. (Consider _"is 14 greater than 'hello'?"_ - that's an int > string comparison)

Comment: Mr @Luke Briggs  Is there another way to get the MAX value in this field?can i convert from string or object to int

Comment: @AhmedKareem You'd always have to compare int with another int :) See e.g. [How to select min and max values of a column in a datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442525/how-to-select-min-and-max-values-of-a-column-in-a-datatable) - this is casting too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If `id` is numeric type, you can try [`DataTable.Compute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute) :

```
int max = Convert.ToInt32( amDataSet.students.Compute("max(id)", "") );
```

or using the [`Enumerable.Max`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max) LINQ extension :

```
int max = amDataSet.students.Rows.Cast<DatRow>().Max(r => Convert.ToInt32(r["id"]));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving the problem @Slai