# Find min/max datetime in datatable rows

Tags: c#, datatable, minmax

I have a data table that contains a "CreateDate" and an "UpdateDate" columns. I am trying to find the smallest CreateDate and largest UpdateDate. It is not difficult but columns can contain NULL (or DBNull) and this is tripping me. I was using the following:

```
DateTime dtMin = DateTime.MaxValue;
DateTime dtMax = DateTime.MinValue;

foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    DateTime dtCreateDate = dr.Field<DateTime>("CreateDate");
    DateTime dtUpdateDate = dr.Field<DateTime>("UpdateDate");
    dtMin = dtMin > dtCreateDate ? dtCreateDate : dtMin;
    dtMax = dtMax > dtUpdateDate ? dtMax : dtUpdateDate;
}
```

Until I hit a row with a NULL date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to check DBNull.Value and null before you parse values to DateTime because DateTime datetype cannot contain null values. 
Remember that DBNull.Value and object null are 2 different things

By declaring DateTime?, dtCreateDate, dtUpdateDate can contain null value. Then, if you receive a null value, you can skip to compare it with dtMin and dtMax.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    DateTime? dtCreateDate = dr["CreateDate"] == DBNull.Value || dr["CreateDate"] == null ? (DateTime?) null : dr.Field<DateTime>("CreateDate");
    DateTime? dtUpdateDate = dr["UpdateDate"] == DBNull.Value || dr["UpdateDate"] == null ? (DateTime?) null: dr.Field<DateTime>("UpdateDate");


    dtMin = dtCreateDate == null ? dtMin : (dtMin > dtCreateDate ? dtCreateDate : dtMin);
    dtMax = dtUpdateDate == null ? dtMax : (dtMax > dtUpdateDate ? dtMax : dtUpdateDate);

}
```

Comment: I thought about this, but if in first iteration I found a valid dtCraeteDate and in the next iteration I get a NULL date to compare, I don't want to set dtCreatDate back to DateTime.MinValue.

Comment: I updated my suggestion. Declare DateTime? which allow you to contain null value

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the value on the datarow is null before proceeding:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
     {
       if (dr["CreateDate"] != null && dr["UpdateDate"] != null)
         {
           //TODO: Logic here
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Min & Max compute that are supported by data tables. Other option is to use LINQ to find min & max. For reference please see answer on following link.
[How to select min and max values of a column in a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442525/how-to-select-min-and-max-values-of-a-column-in-a-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

This map help you

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    DateTime? dtCreateDate = (DateTime?)dr["CreateDate"];
    DateTime? dtUpdateDate = (DateTime?)dr["UpdateDate"];
    dtMin = (dtCreateDate != null && dtMin > dtCreateDate) ? dtCreateDate.Value : dtMin;
    dtMax = (dtUpdateDate != null && dtMax < dtUpdateDate) ? dtUpdateDate.Value : dtMax;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Here use coalescing operator and conditional operator ,for managing the  conditions :*

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    // Collecting data from DataRow
    DateTime? dtCreateDate =dr.Field<DateTime?>("CreateDate")??(DateTime?)null;
    DateTime? dtUpdateDate=dr.Field<DateTime?>("UpdateDate")??(DateTime?)null;

    // Manupulating condition to get required result
    dtMin = dtCreateDate != null ?(dtMin > dtCreateDate ? dtCreateDate : dtMin) : dtMin;
    dtMax = dtUpdateDate != null ?(dtMax > dtUpdateDate ? dtMax : dtUpdateDate): dtMax;
}
```